# What is predicted to keep the spinon, orbiton, and holon together in an electron?

Tags: electrons

Recent experiments [(here](http://www.nature.com/nmat/journal/v15/n7/full/nmat4604.html) and [here)](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v485/n7396/full/nature10974.html) indicate electrons are composed of the spinon, orbiton, and holon. Little seems to be known about these.

I am curious what is predicted to keep these three sub-particles locked together? Something like a gluon, perhaps? Or are there no ideas yet about this? (I realize it is a recent discovery so there could be no solid hypotheses yet.)

Comment: If you're going to downvote then at least explain why...

Comment: Not my vote, but your summary doesn't match the article. Electrons _aren't_ composed of "spinons, orbitons and holons". That makes the question nonsensical.

Comment: Spinon, orbiton and holon are [quasiparticles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiparticle), they are not actual constituents of the electron. We know about particles by their interactions, and it appears that in condensed matter physics some phenomena are best described as interactions of new kind of particles which are actually arising from complex collective behavior.

Comment: Looks like a duck and walks like a duck, so easier to say it's a duck, even though.. it's not? OK.